# How to overwrite an SCSS variable based on screen width?

Tags: css, sass

I have a varaible:

```
$font-color: red;
```

How do I overwrite its value on smaller screens?

This did not work:

```
$font-color: red;

@media (max-width: 500px){
    $font-color: blue;
}
```

Also, this is in a global variables file. I want that so whenever on a smaller screen the overwriting of the variable will affect everything in every other file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SCSS, variables are set at compile time and cannot be changed dynamically during runtime. Therefore, if you want to change the value of a variable based on a media query, you need to structure your code differently.

One way to achieve what you want is to use the variable in a CSS rule inside the media query, rather than trying to redefine the variable itself. Here's an example:

```css
$font-color: red;

body {
  color: $font-color;

  @media (max-width: 500px) {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

You might consider using CSS variables, they can be modified at runtime using media queries.

Here's an example:

```css
:root {
  --font-color: red;
}

body {
  color: var(--font-color);

  @media (max-width: 500px) {
    --font-color: blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated my question, while you were answering. So based on this, it's impossible what I want?

Comment: @LaczkóÖrs, does my addition answer your question?

Comment: I combined the two, I defined the SASS variable with the CSS variable, and I modified the CSS variable based on the screen width. So globally I can use the SASS variable, and it correctly uses the desired color based on the screen. I think it would be helpful if you included this in your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, using SASS variables dynamically

```sass
:root {
  --font-color: orange;
  @media (max-width: 500px) {
    --font-color: green;
  }
}
$font-color: var(--font-color);
body {
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, sans-serif;
  background-color: $font-color !important;
}
```